# How to do a simple NOT in ActiveRecord Query Interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm very familiar with using hash arguments to ActiveRecord queries, such as:

```
SomeModel.where(association_id: something.id, status: ACTIVE_STATUSES).exists?
```

and similar. But what if you want to do a simple NOT EQUAL or `!=` or `<>` type condition? My simple case is just to exclude the current object from the query.

The only way I can think of would be this:

```
SomeModel.where("id != ?", self.id).where(association_id: something.id,...)
```

But this seems not very rails-like.

Is there a simpler way, or a way to include the `!=` in the hash conditions?

Comment: Use this https://github.com/ernie/squeel gem for complex queries without hardcoded SQL-snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either drop to the Arel table.
There is a great (pro) Railscast on Arel.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/355-hacking-with-arel

You could also use the Squeel gem.

http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel

In Squeel:

```
SomeModel.where{ id != my_id }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4 has `not`:

```
SomeModel.where.not(id: self.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the only way to include != in a query is using

```
SomeModel.where("id != ?", self.id)
```

That aside, ActiveRecord converts other structures to the right SQL query like in:

```
where(:id => [1,2,3])
```

That will generate "where id in (1,2,3)" , but for != , > , < and such this is the only solution (although I'd be glad to discover otherwise)

Comment: Even if it turns out it is the only way, I'd love to know for sure. Thanks!